# Does the site have a cap on how many reputation points a poster can earn per day?

Tags: support, reputation

I was looking over the various badges the site has to offer, and noticed that a poster can earn a few of them for hitting a built-in upper limit for rep earned in a given day. That's fine, but I'm curious as to what that number is? I used the search here on the meta site and found nothing to indicate an answer.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges

Their names are: Epic, Legendary, and Mortarboard.

Answer (score 5):

At first, I was going to delete my question, but then there is the small chance someone else has a little trouble finding the correct answer to the question.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq

The FAQ for the physics site (not the physics meta site) gives the answer: 200 points per day is the cutoff (although accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit).